# Difference between scoped CSS and "scope" by adding a parent class

Tags: css, vue.js

When building an app using vue, vue-loader and the official boilerplate I noticed `scoped` css is used to limit the CSS to the current component. I don't see the point in this. I have always "scoped" css by defining it inside a wrapper class when I have felt the need for it.

For example in SASS:

```
.some-module {
  h1, h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
  }

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
  }

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }

  a {
    color: #42b983;
  }
}
```

So what do i gain from using scoped CSS instead? Or is it merely just another method to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

If you add css in global file you can import any where , but when you are doing with scoped css it will connect styling with respective component only.

Please refer https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html for more info

**Scoped CSS**

When a  tag has the scoped attribute, its CSS will apply to elements of the current component only. This is similar to the style encapsulation found in Shadow DOM. It comes with some caveats, but doesn't require any polyfills. It is achieved by using PostCSS to transform the following:

```
<style scoped>
.example {
  color: red;
}
</style>

<template>
  <div class="example">hi</div>
</template>
```

Into the following:

```
<style>
.example[data-v-f3f3eg9] {
  color: red;
}
</style>

<template>
  <div class="example" data-v-f3f3eg9>hi</div>
</template>
```

Comment: I understand how it works, what I don't understand is why `.example[data-v-f3f3eg9]` is better than `.data-v-f3f3eg9.example` which I can achieve by just nest all the component classes in a wrapper class with a really intricate name =)

Answer (score 1):

Here your scope is `.some-module` but this scope is global and may be the same in an other website or framework so it's not really isolated, it's just a name.

With scoped CSS, it is more like CSS in an iframe. You can share your *component* without to worry if the name is already taken or not. You encapsulate the style in the component only.

A "hack" to scope classic CSS is to prefix the classes with the name of the app/framework. For example [material design](https://getmdl.io/started/) prefix all the classes with `.mdl-` to avoid clashes.

Comment: Well, what if .some-class was changed to for example .data-v-f3f3eg9. Would I not achieve the same amount of uniqueness?

Comment: It's a way to create a scope yes but it's not a real scope because it's still in the global space.

Answer (score 1):

As **w3.org** puts it *"If the scoped attribute is present, then the user agent must apply the specified style information only to the style element's parent element (if any), and that element's child nodes."*

Read more about scope [here](https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) & [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html).

> As best I can tell, `<style scoped>` has been removed from the specs and
>   even browsers that were supporting it have pulled it.

[image]